# Can't get my ZF2 application to work on a shared server

Tags: zend-framework2

After developing my Zend Framework 2 website in local, I just bought a hosting and deployed it, but can't get it to work!
First of all, my hosting service doesn't allow me to use the public folder as root, so I found this solution (adding an index.php to the root that includes the public/index.php, and an .htaccess that redirects everything to it):
[ZF on shared host](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-on-a-shared-host/)
I tested it in local, and works great, and I can access it from both mysite.loc and mysite.loc/public
However, on remote it doesn't work, and looks like it can't find the classes:

> Fatal error: Class 'Zend\MVC\Controller\AbstractActionController' not found in /web/htdocs/www.mysite.com/home/module/Cycling/src/MyModule/Controller/IndexController.php on line 8

I'm getting crazy and really need some help, what could be the problem if even from root it works in local?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Zend\MVC\Controller\AbstractActionController` is not the correct class name, it should be `Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController` (note the case of 'Mvc'). I'm guessing you developed the site on a case-insensitive file system (such as OS X or Windows), which is why you are only seeing this problem on your shared server.

Comment: Seriously, that was driving me crazy, and I would have never find that out! Thanks a lot!!